# If condition giving error in shell script when checking two strings

Tags: linux, shell

In following shell script I want to perform two different tasks depending on file type,
but it is giving an error: `"[==c]: command not found"`

```
echo "enter file name"
read num
var_check= echo $str |awk -F . '{if (NF>1) {print $NF}}'

if ["$var_check"=="c"];then
    echo "Some task for c"
elif ["$var_check"=="cpp"];then
    echo "Some task for cpp"
else
    echo "Wrong file extension"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

```
if ["$var_check"=="c"];then
```

The `[` command is a command; its name must be surrounded by spaces (put simplistically).

```
if [ "$var_check" == "c" ]; then
```

The last argument, `]`, must also be preceded by a space.  The operands within must also be space separated; they need to be separate arguments.  The rules for the `[[ ... ]]` operator are a bit different, but using spaces helps people read the code even there.  What you wrote is a bit like expecting:

```
ls"-l"/dev/tty
```

to work; it won't.

You also need to double check whether your `test` or `[` operator supports `==`; the normal form is `=`.

---

The line:

```
var_check= echo $str |awk -F . '{if (NF>1) {print $NF}}'
```

This runs the `echo` command with `var_check` set as an environment variable, which is unlikely to be what you wanted.  You almost certainly intended to write:

```
var_check=$(echo $str |awk -F . '{if (NF>1) {print $NF}}')
```

This runs the `echo` and `awk` commands and captures the output in `var_check`.  Use the `$(...)` notation in preference to the older but more complex to use `` `...` `` notation.  In simple cases, they look the same; when you nest them, the `$(...)` notation is far, far simpler to understand and use.

Also, looking on the larger scale (3 lines instead of just 1 line):

```
echo "enter file name"
read num
var_check=$(echo $str |awk -F . '{if (NF>1) {print $NF}}')
```

You read the file name into variable `num`; you then echo `$str` instead of `$num`.  If you've already got `$str` set somewhere earlier in the script (in unshown code), what you've got may be fine.  Taken as a standalone fragment, it isn't right.

You could also simplify the `awk` a little:

```
var_check=$(echo $str |awk -F . 'NF > 1 {print $NF}')
```

This would work the same as what you wrote, but uses fewer parentheses and braces.